# ASP.NET Web API OData v4 Post with BindingModel

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, odata-v4

I have an OData Web API controller that has a POST to insert a UserProfile but so that I don't expose my database entity I would like the Post method to accept a UserProfileBindingModel instead. Is this possible?

At the moment, I have the following in my UserProfiles:

```
[EnableQuery(PageSize = 100, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
   return Ok(_db.UserProfile.ToUserViewModels());
}


[EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] UserProfileBindingModel model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
      return BadRequest(ModelState);

   var userProfile = ToUserProfile(model);

   _db.UserProfile.AddOrUpdate(userProfile);
   _db.SaveChanges();
   return Created(userProfile);
}
```

And this is my ODataConfig.cs file:

```
public static class ODataConfig
{
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
   {
      // OData builder
      var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

      // Register entities
      builder.EntitySet<UserProfile>("UserProfiles").EntityType.Name = "UserProfile";
      builder.EntitySet<UserProfileViewModel>("UserProfileViewModel").EntityType.Name = "UserProfileViewModel";
      builder.EntitySet<UserProfileBindingModel>("UserProfileBindingModel").EntityType.Name = "UserProfileBindingModel";


      // OData model config
      var model = builder.GetEdmModel();
      // OData route config
      config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", model);
   }
}
```

Where UserProfile is:

```
public class UserProfile
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent API for UserProfile is:

```
public class UserProfilesMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserProfile>
{
   public UserProfilesMap()
   {
      // Primary Key
      HasKey(t => t.Id);

      // Properties
      Property(t => t.Id)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
         .HasMaxLength(128)
         .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
      Property(t => t.DateCreated)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("datetime");
      Property(t => t.DateModified)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("datetime");
      Property(t => t.Email)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
         .HasMaxLength(256);
      Property(t => t.Username)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
         .HasMaxLength(256);
      Property(t => t.FirstName)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
         .HasMaxLength(100);
      Property(t => t.LastName)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
         .HasMaxLength(100);
      Property(t => t.DateBirth)
         .IsRequired()
         .HasColumnType("datetime");

      // Table & Column Mappings
      ToTable("UserProfiles");
      Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
      Property(t => t.DateCreated).HasColumnName("DateCreated");
      Property(t => t.DateModified).HasColumnName("DateModified");
      Property(t => t.Email).HasColumnName("Email");
      Property(t => t.Username).HasColumnName("Username");
      Property(t => t.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
      Property(t => t.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");
      Property(t => t.DateBirth).HasColumnName("DateBirth");
   }
}
```

And UserProfileViewModel is:

```
public class UserProfileViewModel
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string FullName { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateBirth { get; set; }
}
```

UserProfileBindingModel is:

```
public class UserProfileBindingModel
{
   public long Id { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsRequired")]
   [EmailAddress(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidEmail")]
   [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustBetweenCharacters", MinimumLength = 6)]
   [Display(Name = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
   public string Email { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsRequired")]
   [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustUnderCharacters")]
   [Display(Name = "FirstName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsRequired")]
   [Display(Name = "LastName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
   [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustUnderCharacters")]
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsRequired")]
   [Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
   [StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustBetweenCharacters", MinimumLength = 6)]
   public string Username { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsRequired")]
   [Display(Name = "Password", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
   [StringLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustBetweenCharacters", MinimumLength = 6)]
   [DataType(DataType.Password)]
   public string Password { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsRequired")]
   [Display(Name = "ConfirmPassword", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
   [StringLength(255, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "MustBetweenCharacters", MinimumLength = 6)]
   [Compare("Password", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordMustMatch")]
   [DataType(DataType.Password)]
   public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "IsRequired")]
   [Display(Name = "DateBirth", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   public DateTime DateBirth { get; set; }
}
```

The Get method works fine, but with the post method I get the following message:

*The entity type 'UserProfileBindingModel' is not compatible with the base type 'UserProfile' of the provided entity set 'Default.Container.UserProfiles'. When an entity type is specified for an OData feed or entry reader, it has to be the same or a subtype of the base type of the specified entity set.*

There must be a way of doing this...any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: what's your POST url? you should put the Post(...) method in the correct controller.

Comment: Hi @SamXu, I recorded a video http://screencast.com/t/wY0pVM6mFwfr Thanks for your help